# Concurrency violation in update command

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have added my access database as a project data source.  I have a defined a select method in the .XSD to pass parameters and return data to a datatable (this queries a portion of my database table).  This datatable is then bound as a datagridview datasource:

```
'dimensioned at class level
Dim dtEntryDetails As New myDataSet.tblTimeTrackingDataTable
Dim entryAdapter As New myDataSetTableAdapters.tblTimeTrackingTableAdapter

'sub to load data does this
dtEntryDetails = entryadapter.Manager_GetDGVDataByUnitAndDate(cboDateSel.Text, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6, CDate(cboDateSel.Text)), cboWorkGroups.Text) 
dgvEmployeeTime.DataSource = dtEntryDetails
```

Everything loads in okay, I have another dropdown that provides views of the data just loaded in.  I then modify the data in the cells of the datagridview (As I suppose you do with that control!) and then would like to save this datatable back into the database.  I figure rather than read and update row by row, I can send the whole datatable back to the database.

I tried doing:

```
entryadapter.Update(dtEntryDetails)
```

But this is giving me:

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected X records.

What am I missing, or how should I be attempting to update the datatable?

Comment: What is the `UpdateCommand` for your adapter?

Comment: @Steve You are right for asking that question; the problem is indeed with the tableadapter update command.